# Shouldn't we move on SciFi stackexchange question that are related to comics characters and have nothing to do with the movie?

Tags: discussion

There are a lot of question on this site like the following:

[Does Deadpool age?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/49175/16465)

[Can Deadpool's looks still be restored?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/49543/16465)

[Why is Deadpool named Deadpool?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/49082/16465)

[Why don't Wolverine's claws grow back with Adamantium?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/35753/16465)

Why are they considered on topic? I think they should be asked on https://scifi.stackexchange.com/

Ps. I have nothing against Deadpool or the Wolverine, those questions are the first two I could find.

Comment: Just because the answers relate to the comic books doesn't mean that the questions only relate to the comic books. That Wolverine question is specifically about the film.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I'd really prefer people stop *answering* questions on Movies & TV with details from the books or comics, because the questions are about the movie canon. I tend to downvote those answers whenever I see them, even if the OP happens to accept it. I also have heard several users point out that they use M&TV instead of SF&F specifically because they don't want to be "spoiled" by extra details from the source material, so I consider it polite to stick to the movies on a site about movies.

Having said that, all of those *questions* are about the movie versions of those characters. As such, they're clearly on-topic here, so there's no reason to migrate them elsewhere.

Comment: I would not *generally* sign your sentiment against comic/book answers, only if those answers fail to make *any* connection back to the movie or even downright contradict it.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson Neither of the answers on the first linked question have any connection to the film at all. http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/49175/does-deadpool-age Same is true of the second one... and the third one.

Comment: @Catija fixed 1 and 3 with movie info/changes. The 2nd one is strictly about the movie as he was never tricked about his looks in the comics. That's a movie only plot line.

Answer (score 5):

Because screw that. Those are on topic here, they are about understanding the movies and characters in the movies.

Let's ignore that Deadpool and Wolverine come from comics or a non movie or tv source. Let's use a similar topic to mutants. [heroes](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heroes), the 2006 tv show basically rips off the modern mutant genre made popular by X-Men. How is [Why were Hiro’s powers so sporadic?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/955/why-were-hiro-s-powers-so-sporadic) or [Do the powers in Heroes manifest only once a generation?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/10507/do-the-powers-in-heroes-manifest-only-once-a-generation) any different than [Why don't Wolverine's claws grow back with Adamantium?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/35753/16465)

That we have a book or non-movie source that can **Inform or fill in gaps** for the movie does not make a series or question off topic.